# SQL - Created And Closed date based on previous row

Tags: sql

hopefully someone can help me. I have a table of data that looks like the below

```
ID   | JobID    | CreatedDate | ClosedDate
3312 |  332     | 01/02/2018  | 03/02/2018
3312 |  223     | 01/02/2018  | 05/02/2018
3312 |  312     | 01/02/2018  | 01/03/2018
3312 |  445     | 01/02/2018  | 04/07/2018
```

The way the data is structured, the created date is always set the date that the first JobID was created. I want to change this so the created date is set to the ClosedDate of the previous JobID. My ideal output would look like the below

```
ID   | JobID    | CreatedDate | ClosedDate
3312 |  332     | 01/02/2018  | 03/02/2018
3312 |  223     | 03/02/2018  | 05/02/2018
3312 |  312     | 05/02/2018  | 01/03/2018
3312 |  445     | 01/03/2018  | 04/07/2018
```

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this? Thanks
Jess

Comment: Can we assume that `ClosedDate` is ***always*** populated?  And what DBMS are you using?  MySQL, SQL Server, RedShift, TeraData, PostgreSQL, Oracle.........

Comment: How should the jobs be ordered to know what the previous one was? It doesn't seem to be by JobID...

Comment: Yep its always populated

Comment: Jobs will be ordered by ClosedDate desc

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server)?

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: Good point, if the dates are some native DATE datatype they will sort easily, and if they're STRING data types, they'll sort "incorrectly" so require converting.

Answer (score 3):

You want `lag()` :

```
select ID, JobID, 
       lag(ClosedDate, 1, CreatedDate) over (partition by id order by ClosedDate) as CreatedDate, 
       ClosedDate
from table t;
```

You didn't stated any DBMS so, `LAG()` might be fail but you can use subquery instead :

```
select t.ID, t.JobID,
       coalesce((select t1.ClosedDate
                 from table t1
                 where t1.id = t.id and t1.ClosedDate < t.ClosedDate 
                 order by t1.ClosedDate desc
                 fetch first 1 rows only
                ), CreatedDate
               ) as CreatedDate, ClosedDate
from table t;
```

Assuming `CreatedDate` & `ClosedDate` are in reasonable format. In the second version you might need `limit` clause or `top (1)`cluase instead of `fetch first ...`.

Comment: You should state for which RDBMS this query would work.  The OP has not yet tagged with his database.

Comment: Assumes `LAG()` to be available, though the OP could well be using MySQL.  At the very least such an assumption should be mentioned ;)  Also assumed that the dates are not strings *(note that the OP shows them as DD/MM/YYYY)*.

Comment: This is perfect thank you, I used the Lag function (which I never used before)